# Python: Cannot import functions of file (git-externals project)

Tags: python

I want to use git-externals from [here](https://github.com/develer-staff/git-externals).
But python complains when using the

`git externals add URL_TO_GIT_REPO`

shell command that it can't import a function from file cli.py of the file git_externals.py

`File "~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git_externals/cli.py", line 55, in cli from git_externals import is_git_repo, externals_json_path, externals_root_path ImportError: cannot import name 'is_git_repo' from 'git_externals' (~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git_externals/__init__.py)`

How it is imported you can see [here](https://github.com/develer-staff/git-externals/blob/a236211be1e124cb10626b1b06e1cebc46b6ace7/git_externals/cli.py#L55).
The files are in the same directory. I also
tried to

`import git-externals`

with

`print(git-externals.__file__)`

to see what file was imported. It is not the expected git-externals.py but `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/git_externals/__init__.py`. Why is python looking after the `__init__`, how can I change this or is it the right behaviour?

regards

Comment: Are you doing this from a notebook or from a python module?

Comment: I expanded the question with more information. But I use the program via a shell command `git externals add`, so your answer is module!?

Comment: Git (the command-line program) is not really relevant here; [tag:git] should not be used. This git-externals thing is an independent program.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to pot a dot before the module, from

`from git_externals import is_git_repo, externals_json_path, externals_root_path`
to

`from .git_externals import is_git_repo, externals_json_path, externals_root_path`.

It think, but I am not 100 % sure that it is because of the `__init__` file and maybe because I am using Debian. The dot shows python that has to look in the same folder as the `__init__` file. And all files are in the same folder.
A good explanation of the use of this file can be found [here](https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html).